# PHP MySQL join two tables query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables ie abstract table and author with one to many relation, for each iteration on while loop I want to display a html table of unique row of data from abstract table with corresponding rows from author table.

This what I did:

```
public function getAll() {
    try {
          $sql = "  SELECT tbl_abstract.abstract_id, tbl_abstract.first_name,
                            tbl_abstract.last_name,tbl_abstract.content,        
                            tbl_author.afirst_name, tbl_author.alast_name, 
                            tbl_author.aaffilition 
                    FROM tbl_abstract  
                        INNER JOIN tbl_author ON  tbl_abstract.abstract_id = tbl_author.abstract_id 
                    GROUP BY tbl_abstract.abstract_id";

          $stmt= $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->execute();
          $count =  $stmt ->rowCount();
          while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          ?>

             <table class="table" >
              <tr>
                <td  align="center" >
                   //data from tbl_abstract
                   <?php echo $row["abstract_id"];  ?>. <?php print($row["abstract_title"]); ?>
                    <?php echo $row["first_name"].'&nbsp;'.$row["last_name"]; ?>,

                    //data from tbl_author
                    <?php echo $row["afirst_name"].'&nbsp;'.$row["alast_name"];?>         
                </td>  
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" ">
                   //data from tbl_abstract
                   <?php print($row["content"]); ?>
                </td>
              </tr>

            </table>
          <?php 
         }          
    }catch(PDOException $e){
       echo $e->getMessage(); 
       return false;
    }  
}
```

There are three records from tbl_author associated with the abstract_id from tbl_abstract but i only get one record instead of 3 of them.Please help

Comment: _Small Note_ There is little point preparing a query if it does not have any bindable parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :-

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM tbl_abstract
        where abstract_id IN (SELECT distinct abstract_id
                              FROM tbl_abstract)";

      $stmt= $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $count =  $stmt ->rowCount();
?>
      <table class="table" >
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      ?>
          <tr>
            <td  align="center" >
               //data from tbl_abstract
               <?php echo $row["abstract_id"];  ?> <?php print($row["abstract_title"]); ?>
                <?php echo $row["first_name"].'&nbsp;'.$row["last_name"]; ?>,
         <?php          
         $sql1 = "SELECT *
                  FROM tbl_author
                  WHERE abstract_id = '".$row["abstract_id"]."'" ;
         $stmt1= $this->pdo->prepare($sql1);
         $stmt1->execute();
         while($row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                //data from tbl_author
                echo $row1["afirst_name"].'&nbsp;'.$row1["alast_name"];
         } ?>         
            </td>
            <td align="center">
               //data from tbl_abstract
               <?php print($row["content"]); ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
       <?php } ?>

        </table>
```

Comment: I Try it but the html table display duplicate record of the same abstract_id from tbl_abstract and each record contain one record row from tbl_author.What I need is the html table to display the single record from tbl_abstact with associated 3 record from tbl_athor

Comment: Ok , then let me modify the query a little bit

Comment: I have edited the SQL statement , can you check the output ?

Comment: Yes, the output still the same with duplicate abstact_id

Comment: Please check the new sql statement , it can't take any duplicate id . Please re-check the new sql statement and use that .

Comment: I copied the same new sql statement,double checked it,I dont why  but some reasons it did not workout

Comment: I think the output is correct , it is showing unique records , one of which has used the same word twice in the name .

Comment: I would like to get output like this [link](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/f29f2388-3891-4a9d-b7c1-270a9821b0db.png)

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly , please run it again and let me know the result .

Comment: Did you checked the code ? If not , run it and you will get your answer .

Comment: You safe my day, This is exactly what I was looking for.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `GROUP BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_abstract.abstract_id, tbl_abstract.first_name, 
    tbl_abstract.last_name,tbl_abstract.content, tbl_author.afirst_name, 
    tbl_author.alast_name, tbl_author.aaffilition 
FROM 
    tbl_abstract  
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_author ON  tbl_abstract.abstract_id = tbl_author.abstract_id
```

Group by is grouping all the authors by the field abstract_id, which means, that it won't return all the authors, but only one for one abstract_id (based on the sorting field, which in this case is probably the primary key, because it is not explicitly defined)..

Comment: @marc_s Try it but the html  table display duplicate record of the same abstract_id from tbl_abstract and each record contain one record row from tbl_author.What I need is the html table to display the single record from tbl_abstact with associated 3 record from tbl_athor